# Send a sheet into pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script

i have this code and i want send by email a sheet in pdf. All works good, but the attachments cant be open. I try send in xslx and work fine, its just the pdf the problem. Sorry for my self-learn english.

```
function enviar_correo(){

  //spreadsheet where the sheet is
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_resp); 

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(fecha));
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

  //get sheet id
  var index = sheet.getSheetId() 

  //subject and body 

  var asunto = "[Progra] Estado de Responsabilidades"; 
  var cuerpo = "Estimados,<br><br>espero hayan tenido una buena semana. "+
    "Adjunto estado de responsabilidades. Favor aquellos que estén atrasados ponerse al día, "+
    "recuerden que es su responsabilidad entregar las notas en las fechas comprometidas.<br><br>"+
    "Saludos<br> Vicente Marambio";

  //url del archivo

  var url ="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+id_resp+"/export?&gid="+index+ "&portrait=true&exportFormat=pdf";

  var archivo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContent();

  //Mail code

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: correos,
    subject: asunto,
    htmlBody: cuerpo,
    attachments:[{fileName:"Estado de responsabilidades "+fecha2+".pdf", content:archivo, mimeType:"application//pdf"}]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

1. Query of `url` is `/export?&gid=`. Please remove `&`.
2. Please modify `application//pdf` of mimeType to `application/pdf`.
3. `fecha2` of filename is not defined.
4. `correos` of `to` is not defined.
5. Please add `{headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}` to the fetch option.

The modified script which is reflected them is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function enviar_correo(){

  //spreadsheet where the sheet is
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_resp); 

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(fecha));
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

  //get sheet id
  var index = sheet.getSheetId() 

  //subject and body 

  var asunto = "[Progra] Estado de Responsabilidades"; 
  var cuerpo = "Estimados,<br><br>espero hayan tenido una buena semana. "+
    "Adjunto estado de responsabilidades. Favor aquellos que estén atrasados ponerse al día, "+
    "recuerden que es su responsabilidad entregar las notas en las fechas comprometidas.<br><br>"+
    "Saludos<br> Vicente Marambio";

  //url del archivo

  var url ="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+id_resp+"/export?gid="+index+ "&portrait=true&exportFormat=pdf";

  var archivo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getContent();

  var fecha2 = "sample"; // added

  //Mail code

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: correos, // Please define this.
    subject: asunto,
    htmlBody: cuerpo,
    attachments:[{fileName:"Estado de responsabilidades "+fecha2+".pdf", content:archivo, mimeType:"application/pdf"}]
  });
}
```

If this doesn't work for your environment, feel free to tell me. At that time, please tell me the error message.

Comment: Amazing, its works!!

This its the solution

{headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}

for what its that option?

Comment: @Vicente Marambio Welcome. Thank you, too. ``UrlFetchApp.fetch()`` has url and option as parameters. The option has also some parameters. ``headers`` is one of them. In your case, access token is given using ``ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()``. You can see other parameters at [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)).

Comment: But why i need that option?

Comment: @Vicente Marambio The access token is used for exporting files. When the access token is not defined, an error occurs.